# Localization FieldCollection Pimcore

Tags: localization, pimcore

Can we use field collection in localized fields or vice versa. As while going through pimcore 4 document
https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE4/Structured+Data+Fields+-+Fieldcollections

I found below statement

If you want to use localized fields inside field collections you have to set the object before calling any localized field - related methods.

But when I tried I was not able to either add field collection in localized field nor vice versa.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't use field collections inside localized fields. But you can use localized fields inside field collections.

The following example hopefully explains it better.

So this will not work:

```
Object
-> Localized fields  
   -> Product name
   -> Product description
   -> Technical data (field collection)
      -> Value
      -> Unit
```

But this will:

```
Object
-> Localized fields
  -> Product name
  -> Product description
-> Technical data (field collection)
   -> Localized Fields
      -> Value
      -> Unit
```

The statement you are citing is referring to adding field collections programmatically.

Comment: Thanks Igor for reply.
But I am not even able to add localized fields for a field collection please refer below image link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Vyf9JeK2gxUVRCcXFkbm1waHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, I guess your version could be the problem. I think the support for localized fields in Field collections was added later on. So try updating if you can. I unfortunately don't know when the support was added.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that its working in pimcore 4. However I am can't upgrade to pimcore 4 for now, but thanks a lot for your time and advice.